# CDI @RequestScoped bean lifecycle

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I defined a RequestScoped bean as below with CDI annotation. I have several pages which use the same bean. When I navigate from page to page. The bean obj keeps the same. Even when I change the session (login wth different user). The bean object is not changed.

According to RequestScoped definition, the bean instance should re-create for each new request. Anything I missed?

I am using JSF/Primefaces. The value input from create.xhtml page can be seen after navigating to detail.xhtml page. In backing bean, the value is not re-assigned.

Thanks,

Zhang

============================================================

`import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;`

`import javax.inject.Named;`

`@Named("targetManager")`

`@RequestScoped`

`public class TargetManager implements Serializable {`
`}`

`======================================`

`create.xhtml:`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      template="../../templates/rapm.xhtml">

<ui:define name="contents">

<h:form id="createform">
  <h:outputLabel id="englishNameLabel">
     <h:outputText id="englishName" value="#{msg['view.label.englishname']}:" />
     <h:outputText id="englishNameStar" value="* " styleClass="mandatory" />
  </h:outputLabel>  
  <p:inputText id="englishTitle" value="#{targetManager.selectedTarget.englishName}" >
    <f:validator id="englishNameValidate1" validatorId="duplicateValidator" />
  </p:inputText>`
```

`======================================`

`detail.xhtml:`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  template="../../templates/rapm.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="contents">

  <p:scrollPanel id="scrollPanel" styleClass="contentPanel ntb" mode="native">

     <h:outputText id="englishName" value="#{msg['.view.label.englishname']}:"/>
       <h:outputText id="englishNameValue" value="#{targetManager.selectedTarget.englishName}" />
```

`

Comment: How do you know that the object is not changed?

Comment: I debug the code. The object id is always the same. The values of the bean can be accessed from multiple pages

Comment: Can you please post the part where you debug the code.

Comment: don't know how to post debug code. I just set a checkpoint at the my audit program, which captures some values of bean 'targetManager'. At the point, the bean's id is always the same number when threads from different pages and requests. The number id changes only after restart the app –  Xunan Zhang 5 hours ago

Answer (score 2):

CDI indeed creates a new object for each request but not for your servlet or what you are using.

Assuming you have a servlet, then the servlet instance is created only once and if you inject a request scoped bean into this servlet, then CDI is not able to exchange the bean instance within the servlet since this could result in unpredictable states. Thus CDI creates a proxy instance for the servlet which remains the same all the time the servlet lives. This is why you get only this single id for the bean instance, you are retrieving the id of the CDI proxy object, not of the underlying bean. When a new request comes in, CDI creates a new bean instance and backs the proxy with this bean for this specific request.

Comment: Your explanation is reasonable.
One thing remains unclear:according the proxy explanation,values from proxy should change for each new bean (request). But why the bean's property value (with EL) input from one page can be seen in another page without re-assigning? thanks

Comment: Can you post a more detail about your setup? the bean, the page, ... there must be something else that has another scope.

Comment: Best would be if you could share a minimal project with us that shows this behavior. Thanks

Comment: post 2 simplified pages.
not sure the setup, web.xml and faces-config.xml do not involved the scope. other parts are complicate. seems not involve, either

Comment: The first a few Java lines are the definition of the target manager. It contains a model instance 'selectedTarget'. The model has a 'englishName' attribute. I am expecting the value of the 'englishName' change for different requests

Comment: Hi Shi, you said in above comment: 'there must be something else that has another scope'. Where might be the scope which can affect the target manager's scope? BTW, I don't have CDI beans.xml file in my app. Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, try adding beans

Comment: Sorry, wrong button on my mobile ;) try adding beans.xml otherwise CDI will be disabled for your deployment and i think the scope won't take affect.

Comment: I will add it on Monday to see what it happends. Thanks

Comment: I added empty beans.xml file. Now I have lots of build errors. So I am sure that our project is not working on real CDI mode. It is a big project. Updating will involve lots issues. It will take time.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is recreated by outputting the time it is created. You will see that it outputs different time everytime which means it is recreated on every request.

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
@Named("targetInstructionManager")
@RequestScoped
public class TargetInstructionManager implements Serializable { 
    public TargetInstructionManager (){
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
}
```

Comment: I have a 

`@PostConstruct

 public void init(){}`
and I also put your constructor in the class. Both are called only when deployed. When and after app start, it is never called any more